# librashlitics does not exists in build

Tags: google-fabric

I'm trying to integrate Fabric Crashlitics with native code. I had crashes in native code but there are no any records about them in fabric. probably I have not integrated fabric correctly. I do not see libcrashlitics.so in apk.

in my gradle there are

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    manifestPath 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
}
```

I found good article but version is 2.0.0
https://paramsen.github.io/crashlytics-ndk-and-cmake/?readNext=true

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. Here's how to [setup](https://fabric.io/downloads/gradle/ndk) Crashlytics NDK in your app.

1. Add these lines to your build.gradle:

   `buildscript {
     repositories {
       jcenter()
       maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
     }
     dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
       // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
       // quickly to Android tooling updates
       classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
     }
   }`

2) Also in your app's build.gradle apply the Fabric plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

3) Add the Fabric repo:

```
repositories {
  jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }
```

4) Enable NDK as you mentioned:

```
crashlytics {
  enableNdk true
}
```

5) Add Crashlytics and Crashlytics NDK AARs:

```
dependencies {
  // Crashlytics Kit
  compile 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3'
  // NDK Kit
  compile 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.0.4'
}
```

6) In your Java code, add these imports:

```
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;
import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics;
import com.crashlytics.android.ndk.CrashlyticsNdk;
```

7) Init Fabric as follows:

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new CrashlyticsNdk());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);
  }
```

and you're done. Don't forget to upload symbols as well:

```
~ username$ ./gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease
```

Comment: In instruction was not mentioned about compile 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.0.4'

Comment: Can you share which instructions you are referring to?